# How to get part of a key in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key

How do I get `1` from a hash that looks like this?

```
{{1=>2} => 3}
```

Comment: My question is how did you end up with that hash structure? It's not the usual way to use a hash key or to design a hash.

Comment: Well, key can be anything, right? :) I am parsing logs and I wanted to have `{status => relay}` hash as a key in another hash. Example for user@yahoo.com: `{{"bounced"=>"k.mx.mail.yahoo.com"}=>1, {"sent"=>"127.0.0.1"}=>4, {"bounced"=>"g.mx.mail.yahoo.com"}=>1, {"bounced"=>"c.mx.mail.yahoo.com"}=>2}`

Comment: I'd like to see your code to get the mail host for all bounced records, or the total number of all bounced records.

Comment: Meaning it would be hard to get it from this data structure? Well, I am not interested in stats, just in not sending any mail to users that bounce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{{1=>2} => 3}.keys
#=> [{1=>2}]

{{1=>2} =>3 }.keys[0]
#=> {1=>2}

{{1=>2}=>3}.keys[0].keys
#=> [1]

{{1=>2}=>3}.keys[0].keys[0]
#=> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{{1=>2}=>3}.keys.first.keys.first
```